# Find the total amount for each day. Amount calculated from all previous days if day is not Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-intelligence

This was a question asked in a BI Engineer interview. I could not solve it and still scratching my head around it. Although, I used lag window function using case statements, but the interviewer did not seem to get impressed by it. Is there any other way it can be solved?

Below is the input data. If the day of the week is Monday, then it does not add the previous day's amount. It adds the amount for previous days only till Sunday which only sums up the total amount for the week.

```
Date    Amount  
27-Sep-2021 1   
28-Sep-2021 13  
29-Sep-2021 15      
30-Sep-2021 20      
1-Oct-2021  9       
2-Oct-2021  20      
3-Oct-2021  8       
4-Oct-2021  2   
5-Oct-2021  9       
6-Oct-2021  11  
7-Oct-2021  15  
8-Oct-2021  8   
9-Oct-2021  16  
10-Oct-2021 3   
11-Oct-2021 3   
12-Oct-2021 18
```

And below is the expected output

```
Date    Amount  WTD
27-Sep-2021 1   1   
28-Sep-2021 13  14
29-Sep-2021 15  29  
30-Sep-2021 20  49  
1-Oct-2021  9   58  
2-Oct-2021  20  78  
3-Oct-2021  8   86  
4-Oct-2021  2   2   
5-Oct-2021  9   11  
6-Oct-2021  11  22
7-Oct-2021  15  37
8-Oct-2021  8   45
9-Oct-2021  16  61
10-Oct-2021 3   64
11-Oct-2021 3   3
12-Oct-2021 18  21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window function `sum() over()` should help here.   Also note that I use `SET DATEFIRST 1` to set Monday as the the first day of the week.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d956624b9ef5eaf5b286dda7c66462ba)**

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
 
Select *
      ,WTD = sum(Amount) over (partition by datepart(Week,Date) order by Date rows unbounded preceding)
 from YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Hey John. Thank you very much for the answer. What happens if you don't use rows unbounded preceeding

Comment: @Anas Still works.   It is more performant using rows unbounded and also handles duplicate dates properly

Comment: Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1b6f74e8bec9b1391a9cf6cfdebeefed  Notice that I have a duplicate date on the 28th

Comment: @Anas Look again, the 28th has the same WTD when is should be incremented

Comment: Yes, John.  The difference seems to appear in the case of duplicates. Got it!!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, sitting at a terminal, I have the luxury of fixing syntax errors as they appear. I always try to remind myself to determine if a value can play into ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING when a gap problems arises.

> ```
> CREATE Table MyTable(Date DATETIME, Amount INT)
> INSERT MyTable VALUES
> ('27-Sep-2021',1),
> ('28-Sep-2021',13),
> ('29-Sep-2021',15),
> ('30-Sep-2021',20),
> ('1-Oct-2021',9),
> ('2-Oct-2021',20),
> ('3-Oct-2021',8),
> ('4-Oct-2021',2),
> ('5-Oct-2021',9),
> ('6-Oct-2021',11),
> ('7-Oct-2021',15),
> ('8-Oct-2021',8),
> ('9-Oct-2021',16),
> ('10-Oct-2021',3),
> ('11-Oct-2021',3),
> ('12-Oct-2021',18)
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

16 rows affected

> 

> ```
> --Monday=2
> ;WITH Grouped AS
> (
>   SELECT *,
>       IsMondayGroup = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)   
>   FROM 
>       MyTable
> )
> SELECT 
>   Date,Amount,
>   GroupSum = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY IsMondayGroup ORDER BY Date) 
> FROM
>   Grouped
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                    | Amount | GroupSum
> :---------------------- | -----: | -------:
> 2021-09-27 00:00:00.000 |      1 |        1
> 2021-09-28 00:00:00.000 |     13 |       14
> 2021-09-29 00:00:00.000 |     15 |       29
> 2021-09-30 00:00:00.000 |     20 |       49
> 2021-10-01 00:00:00.000 |      9 |       58
> 2021-10-02 00:00:00.000 |     20 |       78
> 2021-10-03 00:00:00.000 |      8 |       86
> 2021-10-04 00:00:00.000 |      2 |        2
> 2021-10-05 00:00:00.000 |      9 |       11
> 2021-10-06 00:00:00.000 |     11 |       22
> 2021-10-07 00:00:00.000 |     15 |       37
> 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 |      8 |       45
> 2021-10-09 00:00:00.000 |     16 |       61
> 2021-10-10 00:00:00.000 |      3 |       64
> 2021-10-11 00:00:00.000 |      3 |        3
> 2021-10-12 00:00:00.000 |     18 |       21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0675bcfda37a6e4db469bc5d40a2da8)*